# StringBuilder value and String value can't be compared correctly

Tags: c#, string, compare, stringbuilder

I tried to compare `StringBuilder` value and `String` value. Even though they have same value why my function returns false?

```
bool checkPalindrome(string inputString)
{

    StringBuilder reverse = new StringBuilder();
    char[] inputStringArray = inputString.ToCharArray();

    for (int i = inputStringArray.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        char letter = inputStringArray[i];
        reverse.Append(letter);
    }

    return (reverse.Equals(inputString));

}
```

Comment: BTW, your reversing logic will fail for composited character like: `ёе`. Reversed string will be `ёе`, not `её`.

Comment: Thanks for warning, i'll try to improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most types in C# will only be equal if they are the same type, among other requirements. Each type can define its own Equals method that controls what equality means for that type.

Here, you want to compare `reverse.ToString()` to `inputString`.  `StringBuilder.ToString()` returns the contents of the instance as a string.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out both your entites are *not* the same type.

Now the `Equals()` method is a method on every `object` as [`Object.Equals()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.100).aspx).

As `Object.Equals()` accepts an `object` and is not type bound you can compare any `object` to any other `object`.

**MSDN REMARKS**

> The default implementation of Equals supports reference equality for reference types, and bitwise equality for value types. Reference equality means the object references that are compared refer to the same object. Bitwise equality means the objects that are compared have the same binary representation.

Now this method can be overriden as it is a `virtual` method which allows developers to compare different object types against the current object type.

**Answer to Your question:**

> Even though they have same value why my function returns false?

As `StringBuilder` is not a `String` the result will always be `false`; *Reference equality means the object references that are compared refer to the same object.*

**Answer to the Real Question**

> How can I compare if a StringBuilder contents is Equal to a string.

As others have pointed out all you need to do is call the `StringBuilder.ToString()` method to generate a string to compare.

As `return (reverse.ToString().Equals(inputString));`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know how Equals() works. I learned more than i've asked.

Comment: @korem7 glad you have. Better to understand why they are **not** equal then how to make them equal.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the `StringBuilder` a string first.

```
return (reverse.ToString().Equals(inputString));
```

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to compare StringBuilder value and String value. Even though they have same value why my function returns false?

To put it simply, `StringBuilder` and `string` are not the same `types`.

`StringBuilder` must be converted to a `string` in order to  compare it against another `string`. this ensures that you're comparing the same `types`.

**change this:**

```
return (reverse.Equals(inputString));
```

**to this:**

```
return (reverse.ToString().Equals(inputString));
```